# PHP: Registration form don't send to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I got a registration form that currently not send data or the function isn't work as expected.

First page got all the form that must to be sent to sign-up.php using POST method, all the user input will be striped and if all the request form data is putted by user will be sent to method `register`in `USER` class.
The class handle the mysql submission.

The database connection work as expected.

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="sign-up.php" method="POST">

   <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Errore:</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Indirizzo e-Mail">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
       <div class="col-md-9">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
       </div>
   </div>
   [ ... Striped Code ...]                         
   <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Registrati"/>
        <button id="btn-fbsignup" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facebook"></i>Registrati con Facebook</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**sign-up.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('core/class.user.php');
$user = new USER();
var_dump($_POST);
if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $uname       = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $umail       = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $upass       = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $firstname   = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname    = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
    $address     = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
    $cap         = strip_tags($_POST['cap']);
    $city        = strip_tags($_POST['city']);
    $prov        = strip_tags($_POST['prov']);
    $tel         = strip_tags($_POST['tel']);

    if($uname=="")   {
        $error[] = "provide username !";
    }
    else if($umail=="")  {
        $error[] = "provide email id !";
    }
    else if(!filter_var($umail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  {
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address !';
    }
    else if($upass=="")  {
        $error[] = "provide password !";
    }
    else if(strlen($upass) < 6){
        $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row['user_name']==$uname) {
                $error[] = "sorry username already taken !";
            }
            else if($row['user_email']==$umail) {
                $error[] = "sorry email id already taken !";
            }
            else
            {
                if($user->register($uname,$umail,$upass,$firstname,$lastname,$address,$cap,$city,$prov,$tel)){
                    $user->redirect('sign-up.php?joined');
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
if ($_GET['joined']) {
    print 'Registrazione completata';
}
?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
class USER
{

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname, $umail, $upass, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $cap, $city, $prov, $tel)
    {
        try {

            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass,disk_quota, details_nome, details_cognome, details_indirizzo, details_cap, details_citta, details_provincia, details_telefono) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass, '209715200', :firstname, :lastname, :address, :cap, :city, :prov, :tel)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":firstname", $firstname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lastname", $lastname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":address", $address);
            $stmt->bindparam(":cap", $cap);
            $stmt->bindparam(":city", $city);
            $stmt->bindparam(":prov", $prov);
            $stmt->bindparam(":tel", $tel);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    [... striped rest of class code ...]
    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
  }
  [... striped rest of class code ...]
```

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php
class Database
{   
   private $host = "localhost";
   private $db_name = "c9";
   private $username = "andreaem_dev";
   private $password = "";
   public $conn;

   public function dbConnection()
   {

       $this->conn = null;    
       try
       {
           $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name . ";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password);
           $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
      }
   }
```

**MySQL log**

MySQL log return only the initial connection to database

```
170314  4:09:26   163 Connect   andreaem_dev@localhost on c9
163 Quit
```

**var_dump() of POST data**

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/auth/sign-up.php:5: array(12) { 'email' => string(19) "johndoe@example.com" 'username' => string(7) "johndoe" 'firstname' => string(4) "John" 'lastname' => string(3) "Doe" 'address' => string(15) "Fantasy Road,14" 'cap' => string(6) "010101" 'city' => string(4) "Roma" 'prov' => string(4) "Roma" 'tel' => string(13) "+395551234567" 'passwd' => string(8) "jdoe1234" 'repasswd' => string(8) "jdoe1234" 'submit' => string(10) "Registrati" }
```

**Behavior**
When the form is submitted to `sign_up.php`I got a blank page, except for the `var_dump()` print-out. Nothing where inserted in database and no errors shown

I hope that I've put all the needed to understand where the problem is.

Comment: So what is the question where is the problem? what error do you get after submitting the form?

Comment: It don't send the data, no errors, It just do nothing. I got a blank page except for the `var_dump()`

Comment: have you tried to use `google chrome inspector`  to inspect that?

Comment: Where is  "$user->is_loggedin()" function defined .  are you redirected or there is some error  .

Comment: `Chrome Inspector` return the code of a blank page, only `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. The `is_loggedIn()` method is part of the striped code in `class.user.php` and currently work as expected in other parts of the project

Comment: where are you importing `new Database();` ?

Comment: remove this portion and test again. if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

Comment: show your `is_loggedin()` method

Comment: @CodeGodie database class where imported in top of user.class.php including database.php file. `user.class.php` updated in question adding `is_loggedIn()` method

Comment: @DilDilshan removing the is_loggedin part not changed the behavior.

Comment: what is the point of your `$error` array if youre not using it?

Comment: @CodeGodie I don't tried this, and removing al the if blocks leaving just the `try { .. }` the form where submitted and I can read the row in database, so the error is in that block of code

Comment: show your `dbConnection()` method. Are you passing `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)` to your PDO ? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @CodeGodie I say the error is in the check of input completition, I will delete this part and check with jQuery. As I delete all the block of IF the code work and the user is created

Comment: perhaps. Give it a go.

Comment: However, if you had errors your `$errors` array would populate. You should do a `var_dump($errors)` after your last `else` to see if you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CodeGodie help, I've found that the problem is in the IFs blocks located at `sign_up.php` page, removing this the code work as expected and the user is created.

I will manage that using jQuery that is more user friendly too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this statement `if($user->is_loggedin()!="")` because `true!=""` was true if the user logged in, then you are redirected to the `home.php`, replace it with this one:

```
if(!$user->is_loggedin())
```

Comment: As you can see in the question, the `var_dump()` of POST data show that all the input fields are submitted to `sign_up.php`

Comment: Thanks but I didn't be redirected to home.php

Comment: So this means that there's  a problem with redirect method.

Comment: that could be a possibility.

Comment: If you are using `header  ()` to redirect then it will not work because you have `var_dump ()` before it, just remove `var_dump`

Comment: Headers must be sent to the user before any other contents, else you will get an error, just check your log files.